# How to append contents of multiple files into many files by group

Tags: bash, file, concatenation, grouping

I need to output many different group-specific text files, by concatenating the contents of same-group files only. The order of file contents to be concatenated within each group is critical and must be maintained as shown. Specifically I have these files (toy sized example for dev; massive size for real):

```
$ find . -name "*.doc" | sort -k1 -k2 -t'.'
./403and780.bunk_2018-02-09.doc
./immortalis.bunk_2018-03-01.doc
./KryptoFreak405.bunk_2018-03-01.doc
./kygiacomo.bunk_2018-02-09.doc
./Mimi108.bunk_2018-03-02.doc
./namohysip.bunk_2018-02-09.doc
./scarletcrawford.bunk_2018-02-10.doc
./SDsc0rch.bunk_2018-02-09.doc
./SDsc0rch.bunk_2018-02-10.doc
./SDsc0rch.bunk_2018-03-02.doc
./shitpostlord4321.bunk_2018-02-09.doc
./thwinks.bunk_2018-03-02.doc
```

Basically I want the 3 SDsc0rch files' contents put into 1 group file in the order shown. There is only 1 403and780 file which similarly gets into its 1 group file, etc. The group value like 403and780 will serve as the name of the newly created file.

So here's my best code so far. I looked at awk and datamash but cannot seem to get help from them.

```
$ find . -name "*.doc" | sort -k1 -k2 -t'.' | xargs cat #(or paste)

$ paste --serial SDsc0rch.bunk_2018-02-09.doc SDsc0rch.bunk_2018-02-10.doc SDsc0rch.bunk_2018-03-02.doc > SDsc0rch.doc
```

I hand-made a simulated paste command that only works right for one particular group (SDsc0rch). Thus the above code is not right, but something like xargs cat or xargs paste can catch the filenames emitted for each group, if I could only get group-wise emissions from some Gnu program.

I really need the group files emitted group-wise to cat or paste, and then do this for all the groups found.

Due to massive number of files, it's over 40GB on disk, and this is just a dev sample, I would prefer not to attempt to load all file contents into working memory before writing the group files. I don't have 40GB of RAM.  Instead I would rather process only a group at a time:  Concat only the file group that my sort command has identified, then move on to the next group.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r group; do
    ifs_bak=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    declare -a files=( $(find . -name "$group*.doc" | sort -k2 -t".") )
    IFS=$ifs_bak
    cat "${files[@]}" > "${group}.doc"      # or "paste" as you like
done < <(find . -name "*.doc" -print0 | while read -r -d "" file; do
    tmp=$(basename "$file"); echo "${tmp%%.*}"
done | sort | uniq)
```

**Explanations:**

The task can be divided into two steps:

1. to extract the group name from the filenames
2. to find files which belong to each group

The 1st step is performed in the fragment:

```
find . -name "*.doc" -print0 | while read -r -d "" file; do
    tmp=$(basename "$file"); echo "${tmp%%.*}"
done | sort | uniq
```

which outputs:

```
403and780
KryptoFreak405
Mimi108
SDsc0rch
immortalis
kygiacomo
namohysip
scarletcrawford
shitpostlord4321
thwinks
```

- `-print0` is necessary to handle a filename which may contain whitespaces.
- The following line `tmp=$(basename "$file"); echo "${tmp%%.*}"` extracts the group name by removing dirname and substring after "." in the filename.
- `sort` and `uniq` clean-ups the group names by removing redundant names.

Then the output above is passed to the `while` loop as the 2nd step:

- `IFS` is temporarily assigned to a newline to create an array from the output of `find`
- Then the array `files` holds the filenames which belong to the currently processed group.

It is recommended to test with a small subset of your files in advance. In addition it would be better to consider where to store the concatenated files. The same directory as the existing files may not be a good location.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting program. Thank you